# Why is address translation needed?

Tags: operating-system

I am taking an operating systems class, and they introduced the concept of address translation. While a program is running, all memory accesses will be translated from virtual to physical. My question is: a lot of memory addresses are given to the program by the OS, and thus can be the physical addresses themselves. What types of memory requests does the program initiate all by itself (without an address given by the OS), and thus would be virtual addresses?

The address of the stack is pre-set by the OS in the stack pointer before the program starts running, and so the stack pointer can hold the physical address. Heap addresses returned by malloc are returned by the OS -- thus, the OS can return the physical address, since that address is stored in some variable and is transparent to the program. So what addresses does the program itself access that need to be translated to physical addresses? So far, the only examples I can think of are: 1) instruction addresses (jump commands have the instruction address hardcoded in the program code) and 2) maybe static variable addresses (if it's not stored in a register by the OS). Are there any more examples/am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the example that I gave in my answer (see below) convince you? If so, I suggest to accept the answer by checking it to mark the question as answered. If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest example why address translation is extremely useful:
The physical address space is usually partitioned into pages, e.g. 4k large.
Processes have their own virtual address space, that is also partitioned into pages of the same size.
Address translation, which is done by a memory management unit under control of the operating system, maps any virtual page to any physical page, for every page independently.
It is thus possible to combine arbitrary pages of a fragmented physical memory to continuous virtual pages.
This allows to use the physical memory much more effectively than without address translation.